# Can you see mistake in this Html/Css code?

Tags: html, css

Here I got division #about:

```
<div id="about" onMouseOver="document.getElementById('screen').style.top=60" onMouseOut="document.getElementById('screen').style.top=0"></div>
```

I want to achieve changing another's division coordinates when mouse gets over this one.First time it worked perfect but now it doesn't want to move.For example, when I replace `top` with `background` it works.

Here's division I want to affect:

```
    <div id="screen">
    <a id="msg"></a>
</div>
```

And style of it:

```
    #screen
    {
        height:25px;
        width:500px;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;
        margin:auto;
        border-style:solid;
        border-radius:10px;
        text-align:center;
        font-style:italic;
        opacity:0;
        background-image:url("http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/light-wooden-background.jpg");
        transition:opacity 1s, top 0.4s;
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: You need to specify the units (I assume pixels so `"60px"`)

Answer (score 3):

You are setting `top` to a Number. CSS lengths (other than `0`) must have units.

```
.style.top = '60px'
```

(In Quirks mode, browsers will ignore the requirement in the CSS specification to ignore rules with invalid properties and will assume pixels, this is likely why it worked the first time.)